# Pushing multiple images to docker hub in Jenkins automatically

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, cicd

In the Jenkins file we built multiple docker images. We need to push the images automatically to docker hub without having to write the name of the images every time. Note that the number of images built each time could be different and we have to track what are the new images built and only push those images in Jenkins script.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no readymade tactic for this. You would need to design it.

1. Findout which new images are built. For this, you may compare the checksum with pushed images.
2. Push every image in separate thread. Basically use multithreading or background job